# How do I navigate to the Responses tab?

Tags: support, navigation, responses

When coming to superuser.com yesterday I was presented a link to a (very useful) Responses tab (at the top of the page): https://superuser.com/users/recent/1495/2009-07-22/2009-07-23?tab=responses.  But I can't figure out how to navigate there.

Comment: I struggled with the same usability issue.  I've added a feature request to address it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45700/augment-envelope-with-recent-or-activity-or-responses-link.

Comment: See also this FAQ request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/how-do-i-view-my-recent-replies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click your name (in the top bar), and then the 'responses' tab.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I never knew that clicking the envelope and clicking your username took you to different screens!!!

Answer (score 1):

The envelope no longer exists, and the format/content of the responses tab has changed.

To answer the question as stated, though, the responses tab is located at `http://SITENAME/users/USERID/USERNAME?tab=responses`.

For example, here on MSO, my responses tab is at

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand?tab=responses