# How do I view the recent replies to things I have written?

Tags: support, reputation, recent-activity, comment-replies, faq-proposed

How can I see recent activity, such as when someone answers one of my questions, leaves a comment reply to me, edits one of my posts, or votes on my posts?

How do I see recent activity on my "favorites"?  How do I view my recent reputation and badge changes?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Global inbox

You can view recent responses (comment replies and answers only) through the Stack Exchange icon on the upper left of the page:

[image: global inbox screenshot]

It also lights up for new activity:

[image: one new reply screenshot]

Comment: How would I view recent replies that I had made (instead of recent replies that other users had made)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - I think the answer is: click on your avatar or reputation score (which are more to the right in that same black strip at the top of the page); ensure you are in the "activity" tab (rather than "profile"); and then choose the "all activity" subtab.