# Accessibility of the "other" activity page

Tags: support, recent-activity, activity-summary

The "regular" activity page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/[user_id_here]?tab=activity) is accessible by clicking the Activity tab on one's profile page. When there is activity on one's questions or favorites, etc., the browser shows a banner across the top saying, for example, "You have 1 new response." Clicking that banner opens the "other" activity page, entitled **Recent Activity** (https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/[user_id_here]/?tab=responses), which presents similar but different details.

I find this other activity page much more useful for some things. For example, it makes it easier than the reputation graph to see exactly what has bumped up my reputation. Also, it categorizes activity by tabs, which is quite helpful.

Now that I have bookmarked this Recent Activity page I have it readily available, but I am just wondering why it is somewhat hidden (i.e. does not have a link on the profile page) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view my recent replies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/how-do-i-view-my-recent-replies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the envelope icon at the top of every page.

Comment: Now that you point it out, I can see that as a reasonable way to do it. But I do not think it is all that obvious to some folks who are not aware of it :-)

Comment: @msorens: If that's what you're asking, I've seen it suggested the icon be offset to make it more obvious, but don't have the link handy.

Comment: Is it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43802/increase-the-size-of-the-recent-envelope-image that you are thinking of?