# notify on new answers for question not ask by me

Tags: support

Hi there,

I checked Unanswered questions where I found one that is intersting to me, I don't know the answer to the question but I want to follow it up (to see I someone has a good answer), there is a way to set a "**notify daily of any new answers**" for that question, just like doing for questions that I've asked ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mark that question as your favourite and you will be notified if there are any changes to your favourite.

Comment: Note this notification comes through your [recent activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/how-do-i-view-my-recent-replies) (the envelope icon).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a straight workaround, but if you are interested in the answers to a question, you can start a bounty on it. While the bounty lasts (7 days), you'll receive notifications of new answers directly in your inbox.